# Hibernate query with @Formula-annotated attribute in order by clause

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, db2, sql-order-by

I have 2 entities:

```
@Entity
class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Contract> contracts= new HashSet<>();

    @Formula("(select count(m.ORDER_ID) from myschema.ORDER_CONTRACTS m where m.ORDER_ID = id)")
    private Integer numberOfContracts;  // this is basically contracts.size()
}
```

and

```
@Entity
class Contract {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String client;
    // some other properties
}
```

When I want to get my orders ordered by `numberOfContracts`, hibernate generates this query for me

```
SELECT order0_.id AS id1_5_,
    (SELECT COUNT(m.ORDER_ID)
        FROM myschema.ORDER_CONTRACTS m
        WHERE m.ORDER_ID = order0_.id) AS formula1_
FROM myschema.order order0_
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(m.ORDER_ID)
        FROM myschema.ORDER_CONTRACTS m
        WHERE m.ORDER_ID = order0_.id) DESC
```

and fails with

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=ORDER0_.ID, DRIVER=4.27.25
```

When I replace the select in the `ORDER BY` with `formula1_` like this:

```
SELECT order0_.id AS id1_5_,
    (SELECT COUNT(m.ORDER_ID)
        FROM myschema.ORDER_CONTRACTS m
        WHERE m.ORDER_ID = order0_.id) AS formula1_
FROM myschema.order order0_
ORDER BY formula1_ DESC
```

I get the expected result.

Is there a way to tell hibernate to use the generated alias (formula1_) instead of replicating the formula in the order by?

**EDIT:**

*How I get my query:*
I'm using an `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController`. This controller offers a endpoint to get all `Orders` by a method like this:

```
@GetMapping("orders")
public List<Order> getOrders(Pageable pageable);
```

When I send a request like `http://localhost:8080/api/orders/sort=numberOfContracts,desc&size=100&page=0`
to the endpoint, the pageable contains the information about ordering. My contoller then calls my

```
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Integer>
```

witch provides this method:

```
Page<Order> findAll(Pageable page);
```

After this point spring and hibernate do their magic.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of HQL query are you using. Hibernate will just do what you tell it to do. You will have to use the HQL alias as well in the order by clause if you want the SQL alias to be used:

```
SELECT o.id, o.numberOfContracts as num
FROM Order o
ORDER BY num desc
```

Comment: Hi, I´m not using a HQL query directly. I´m using a ```org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository``` where I have my ```findAll()``` method. This method takes an ```
org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable``` and that pageable contains my properties which the result should be ordered by. For the example case the property is named "numberOfContracts".

Comment: Spring Data JPA doesn't support that, so the only option to make this work is to use HQL directly. You could also remove the numberOfContracts field and use a DTO projection instead for this method where you can use HQL or SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I´ll have a look into projection